# I'm learning C# and not fully understand properties

Tags: c#

The course I'm using to learn C# has such a code to explain properties

```
public class Person 
{
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    public int Age
    {
       get {
             var timeSpan = DateTime.Today - Birthdate;
             var years = timeSpan.Days/365;

             return years;
       }
    }
}
```

I agree that in the case of `Birthdate` it's reducing the amount of code, but I do not see any benefits of `Age` property? as for me `Age` property only complicating things here, why not create a method to calculate age?

Comment: You could create a method instead. From the caller, which is more natural to you? `Person.Age` or `Person.CalculateAge()`?

Comment: Picking between property and method is up to your style preferences... There is no difference between two except syntax...

Comment: It’s a demonstrative example, and the API design falls into “opinionated”. Using a method would also be suitable. After using C# more, a better understanding of when properties are suitable (as Age is) will be worked out.

Comment: Ya, it's a personal choice.  It's a style of programming, essentially.  int a = aperson.age; or int a = aperson.getage();  I mean, there are things such as Serialization of objects and such. blah ... blah ... whene you might want a property.   Guess, we'll just say stuation.

Comment: You need to understand that there is very very rare (if at all) just one way to accomplish something. And the answer to what way is better is always: "It depends"

Comment: One place I just found out it actually matters is when working with WPF to create GUIs. I had a public variable on a data class. I wanted to link this variable to my GUI in a table.  it turns out that if it is not a property, then you can't do it. In your example, if you wanted to use Age in a window describing the information of the person for instance, you would want to use the property. 

All that said, you could always combine the approaches write a GetAge() method and call that from inside your property get definition. Then the user can use whichever method they like.

Comment: You can leverage the utility of a property, but also have the age calculation [in a method](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sesMIg).  This has the benefit of throwing an error unlike properties, but also makes using the `Person` class intuitive.

Comment: Consider the case where a fully populated `Person` object comes from a database.  The database includes a `Birthdate`, but obviously can't include an `Age`.  At that point, it makes sense for the code to provide a read-only `Age` property if the use-cases for the person include things related to age (can the person legally vote, legally drink, etc. (in fact, you might even include read-only boolean properties for those if it makes sense)).

Comment: Think of Properties as 'smart variables'; one advantage is that they let you _bind_ to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the property `int Age` could just as well be the method `int GetAge()`, but that's also additional verbosity on the calling side.

Age being a property also plays nicely with many other parts of the .NET ecosystem; a data grid component could introspect the objects it's supposed to show and show all properties by default. That's not as straightforward with methods (though you could argue it'd also be a convention thing; a grid could show the results of all `Get*` methods...).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the data grid component yet, and for some reason, in my head, I have a rule that we need to avoid public properties of the class. But as I understand in C# it's more a personal taste of what to use. In the case of the data grid component, my class can have both `Age` and `calculateAge()`, right?   I asked the question because I was worry that I do not understand some benefits of properties.  BTW, what is best practices in such a case 'Age' or `calculateAge` , as for me `calculateAge` is more DDD way??

Comment: Note I said _a_ data grid component, an imaginary one. :) As a rule of thumb, I like to keep possibly heavy operations as methods – if `CalculateAge` needed to do some esoteric Mayan calendar math that could take a while, it'd be a method. But a little bit of date math from the standard library? Pft, that's a property.

Comment: And if there is a long-running calculation you want on a property, you can set up that property to Lazy load, and cache the value to a backing field.

Comment: Well,for method you even do not need lazy loading, no?

Comment: @BogdanDubyk using a method alone, you'd be running the same calculation potentially multiple times.  [Here's one example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v3AO58).  It depends on your use case of course, but it can save you from needing to manually assign caching variables in calling methods, and keeps the class easy to use.

Comment: I see what you mean,but it still can be achieved by a method, assigning/cheching `_someValue ` inside a method body, no?

Comment: Yes of course that would still work, although adding that field assignment inside the method eliminates the possibility of making it static, which can also be beneficial.  I like to think of properties as boiler-plate code one can set up for an API beforehand to simplify using the class.  I think once you implement every trick to avoid using properties, you end up essentially just creating what fundamentally works like a property anyway, but just end up forcing the caller to add extra code.  [Jon Skeet](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/PropertiesMatter) also has some good comments on this.

Comment: Also a good read about this [here on StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62383/what-is-the-point-of-properties)